# Are there archetypes for political intrigues?

Tags: creative-writing, plot, archetypes

> The 7 story archetypes are:
>
> - Overcoming the Monster
> - Rags to Riches
> - The Quest
> - Voyage and Return
> - Comedy
> - Tragedy
> - Rebirth

Are there archetypes for political intrigues? If not what are the building blocks of a political intrigue and what might be the archetypes for these blocks? I am trying to figure out if we can deconstruct political intrigues into a sort of unit and then enumerate all of the possible building blocks we can use to craft a good political intrigue. I am thinking if there are archetypes to stories, there must be archetypes to political intrigues.

Comment: You might want to add that those archetypes are according to Christopher Booker's book ["The Seven Basic Plots: Why We Tell Stories"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Basic_Plots). (I can't really recommend the last part of the book, but the rest was interesting to read.)

Comment: Don't those archetypes apply just as well to political fiction as to any other fiction?  Pick up the daily newspaper, easy to find reports of political goings-on to fill any of those buckets.  Or have I misunderstood your question - are you trying to construct a political intrigue IRL?

Comment: I'm sure you could formulate your own list of elements of intrigues (lying about rivals, betrayal of co-conspirators, forming alliances, helping those in power, acting as a friend with intention of later betrayal, sabotage, idleness, etc). These are at a lower level than the classic plots. I'm not clear if you expect to find a pre-existing list, or you're planning to do it yourself - I don't know any lists but you could certainly try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Archetypes ≠ Literary Genres

Can we then phrase any of the archetypes to fit in the political intrigue genre? Yes, as a matter of fact, you can use all the archetypes to write your literary genre, and political intrigue stories are not an exception.